# Count number of values per quantile in R?

Tags: r

If I have this example:

```
 y=c(5,6,2,51,54,58,37,75,16,25,22,31,6,4)
 x=c(5,6,2,1,4,8,7,5,6,5,2,1,5,4)
 re<-data.frame(x,y)
```

it is easy to estimate `quantile`  using for instance

```
  quantile(x)
```

I need to estimate the number of those pairs in x and y that have x>60% quantile and y <20% quantile?

Comment: is `nrow(re[re$x > quantile(re$x, .6) & re$y < quantile(re$y, .2),])` what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes it does thanks @OttoKässi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following does what you want.

```
with(re, sum(x > quantile(x, 0.6) & y < quantile(y, 0.2)))
#[1] 0
```

You can make of this a function to get different quantiles.

```
sumQuant <- function(DF, qx, qy){
  with(DF, sum(x > quantile(x, qx) & y < quantile(y, qy)))
}

sumQuant(re, 0.6, 0.2)
#[1] 0

sumQuant(re, 0.6, 0.4)
#[1] 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
y=c(5,6,2,51,54,58,37,75,16,25,22,31,6,4)
x=c(5,6,2,1,4,8,7,5,6,5,2,1,5,4)
re<-data.frame(x,y)
res <- re[which(x > quantile(x, .6)),]
res <- res[which(y < quantile(y, .2)),]
```